# How do I add CiviCRM fields to a layout box / container in a form created using webform-civicrm?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I'm on Civi 4.6.17 and Drupal 7. I've created a webform using the [Drupal webform-civicrm module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm). I also have the [Drupal webform layout module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_layout) installed. I've added a new layout box (which seems to mean the same thing as 'layout container' as referred to at the [Drupal webform layout module page](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_layout)). How do I now add fields to my new layout box? Do I need to have the [Drupal Form Builder module](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_builder) installed as well to add fields to the layout box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you're on the Webform tab - you can drag and drop your fields into the Layout Box - here's what it will look like:

[image]

And re: the second part of your question - no - you don't need Drupal Form Builder. When you've downloaded and enabled webform_civicrm module - you'll see a CiviCRM tab (on the far right side) and this is where you tell the module to pull in certain Fields from your CiviCRM:

[image]

Comment: Karin, thanks so much! I've edited my question to clarify what I meant in the second part.

Comment: Excellent! If you have any further questions - don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: I've added another image to my answer - do you have that CiviCRM tab on the far right? That's where you go in and 'grab' your CiviCRM fields.

Comment: Karin, yes, thanks, I had added CiviCRM fields previously. Just needed to move them into the layout box. Thanks again!

Comment: Excellent! Welcome to webform_civicrm! 